# Floating point math, 63.500000 x 2 = 127000000

Tags: c#, .net, hardware

The following code is in question:

```
private const int movementMultiplier = 2;

void Test() {
    XmlNode xnXCoordinate = xd.SelectSingleNode("/data/x");
    XmlNode xnYCoordinate = xd.SelectSingleNode("/data/y");

    int xLoc = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(xnXCoordinate.InnerText)) * movementMultiplier;
    int yLoc = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(xnYCoordinate.InnerText)) * movementMultiplier;
}
```

This code is running on a client's PC (~2009 MacBook running Windows via Bootcamp) with given values/results:

```
xnXCoordinate.InnerText = 63.500000
xnYCoordinate.InnerText = 242.000000

XLoc = 127000000
yLoc = 484000000
```

When I run it, I come up with:

```
xnXCoordinate.InnerText = 63.500000
xnYCoordinate.InnerText = 242.000000

XLoc = 128
yLoc = 484
```

Somehow `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(x))` appears to be losing track of the decimal place. This happens on multiple PCs (never any I have access to test however). There appears to be some type of floating point math error going on here, but I'm not sure what. Can anyone suggest what's going on?

Comment: It's unclear what's wrong. What's the value of movementMultiplier?

Comment: sorry, I'll add that in. It's 2

Comment: It is a culture issue, one where the decimal point is a comma instead of a point.  You'll need to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: Also, what language/cultures are the clients in question running on?

Comment: You're parsing these floats to/from text strings.  What culture are you using? I think it's a string parsing issue more than a floating point issue.

Comment: Everybody is missing the fact that this is not a floating point multiplication problem at all! The multiplication is occurring as integers because the close-parenthesis of the `ToInt32` comes too soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) )
```

?

(Fixed thanks to Pete's comment)

Comment: I'll try this; the result is the same on my computer, I'll send it to the client to test. I hadn't considered this, but it likely seems like the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToSingle(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`? It's the conversion to float that's causing a problem, not the conversion to an int.

Comment: @Pete - you're correct. I verified the problem/solution by using             var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");